# How to get Buttons to recognize what MediaPlayer is being used?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

So I have a class that will play some songs via the MediaPlayer.  I know that you can use code such as:

```
mMediaPlayer.stop();
mMediaPlayer.pause();
```

etc to get a song to do these actions, However I would like to know is there a way to get the button that I press e.g. Stop button or pause Button to recognize which media player is currently being used?  As I have 10 songs within the app and I would like to only use 3 buttons for all of them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want.

You can use ImageView button as control for media playr.

This is example how make start and pause button

button layout

```
<!-- Play Button -->

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_play" />
```

and this java code

```
Button btnPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);

btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // check for already playing
                if(mp.isPlaying()){

                        mp.pause();
                        // Changing button image to play button
                        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_play);

                }else{
                    // Resume song
                        mp.start();
                        // Changing button image to pause button
                        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);
                }   
              }
        });
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: This was helpful however reading over my question I realize that It is not clear.  I would also like it to be for example using the above button to find out whether its it mp1, mp2, mp3 etc that Is playing and then pause the correct song.  Or would I need different play/pause buttons for each.

Comment: Not at the same time, I have radio buttons that play a song based on which one.

Comment: You can make media player and when start any `mp` assign `mp` to general media player and control your media. Note:I didn't try it. This link will help you if you want play all sounds in one media player  [Android Building Audio Player Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider having only one `MediaPlayer` object, and use singleton pattern to reach it. The singleton can manage your resources too. Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595470/how-to-maintain-single-instance-of-mediaplayer-android)

So if your button stops the mediaplayer it will stop the currently loaded song, but you can change the songs that are set to the `MediaPlayer` object